# IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.2 orange highlight in project view

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

[image]

I am a beginner so sorry if this a stupid question. So I open this project that I need to work on, and in the project view it highlights everything in target and generated-sources folder. I can still run and test it but I am worried about what that means and can't find info on it.

I tried reloading the project and download it again but it happens everytime.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-scopes-and-file-colors.html#associate-file-color-with-a-scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just means that those are generated and are excluded from the module.

You can check what folders are marked as source / test / excluded from

```
File -> Project Structure -> Project Settings -> Modules
```